# Python Cerberus - Validating Schema with this Example

Tags: python, validation, cerberus

I am using Cerberus to validate dataframes schema. Using this sample data and code below, the  if-else statement should "data structure is valid", however it returns that the "data structure is not valid". Any insight would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from cerberus import Validator

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35],
    'city': ['New York', 'Paris', 'London']
})

data = df.to_dict()

schema = {
    'name': {'type': 'string'},
    'age': {'type': 'integer', 'min': 18},
    'city': {'type': 'string'}
}

validator = Validator(schema)
is_valid = validator.validate(data)

if is_valid:
    print("Data structure is valid!")
else:
    print("Data structure is not valid.")
    print(validator.errors)
```

Which results:

```
>>> Data structure is not valid.
>>> {'age': ['must be of integer type'], 'city': ['must be of string type'], 'name': ['must be of string type']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing because df.to_dict() returns dictionary with values ad dictionaries

```
data = df.to_dict()
print(data)
>>> {'name': {0: 'Alice', 1: 'Bob', 2: 'Charlie'}, 'age': {0: 25, 1: 30, 2: 35}, 'city': {0: 'New York', 1: 'Paris', 2: 'London'}}
```

If you want your schema to validate this data you need to change it to:

```
schema = {
    "name": {"type": "dict", "valuesrules": {"type": "string"}},
    "age": {"type": "dict", "valuesrules": {"type": "integer", "min": 18}},
    "city": {"type": "dict", "valuesrules": {"type": "string"}},
}
```